# MVC4: Passing parameters from Partial view to another

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hi 
 I have 3 tabs in the Partial View : ClientView:

```
       <div class="tab-content">
         <div class="tab-pane active" id="TabsId-1">
                @{Html.RenderPartial("_GeneralInformation", Model.CLGeneralInfo);}
          </div>
           <div class="tab-pane" id="TabsId-2">                     
                 @{Html.RenderPartial("_GeneralColorsView", Model.CLGeneralColors);}
           </div>
           <div class="tab-pane" id="TabsId-3">                         
                   @{Html.RenderPartial("Cloths", Model.Cloths);}
           </div>
       </div>
```

In _GeneralInformation  I have a combobox "ModelA" and in Cloths I have 3 combobox that I have to filter depending on the value on "ModelA".

So for the first time the 3 combobox on Cloths will be filtered depending on the value of : "ModelA" in _GeneralInformation and each time the user change "ModelA" the 3 combobox are filtered. Can I pass a value from _GeneralInformation to Cloths ?

I tried to apply http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2012/06/cascading-dropdown-knockoutjs-aspnet.html

but the `new { onchange = "FetchStates();"` never trigered

I'm using : MVC4, Bootstrap.

Thanks

Comment: You should post your partial views and the relevant JavaScript. The behavior you're trying to achieve cannot be achieved by server-side code alone.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth, do you have any example since it's my first time to work with MVC, I am newbie thanks

Comment: You should post what have you have tried, there are countless examples on the web (such as the one you provided). You should try something and when it doesn't work, come back with a specific question